# Minecraft Launcher restarts when it is 99% done, why?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

Whenever I start downloading **Minecraft Launcher** and it is 99% done, it restarts automatically. I have tried downloading it three times, each time the same thing happened.

Here what is written in **nativelog**:

```
Native Launcher Version: 34
Operating System: Windows 8.1
Application Hash: 175f2b59d63d17f580f664c195ca8bb82666d0eb
Java Version: 
x64: 1
Starting download of: https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/launcher.json
Created pFile
Content length is 00695D68
Got 200 from server
Download successful
Native launcher outdated!
Hash should be d026a01a83aeaec4111e8c7430ad89b21f3a30f3
Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/win/d026a01a83aeaec4111e8c7430ad89b21f3a30f3/Minecraft.exe
Created pFile
Content length is 006A37B0
Got 200 from server
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out
Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/win/d026a01a83aeaec4111e8c7430ad89b21f3a30f3/Minecraft.exe
Created pFile
Content length is 006A39C0
Got 200 from server
Download aborted
Deleted tmpLauncher.tmp
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I might prevent this?
I have read that slow net is also causing problem, My net speed is 2 mbps.

**I have captured another error, Is this the problem?**
[image]

Comment: It tries to update the launcher and fails because of a timeout. Do you have a very slow internet connection? If not, it could be a problem with a firewall or similar.

Comment: My net speed is 2 mbps , I don't have any firewall or anything like that.

Comment: My problem is solved, I start it downloading , lock the PC went away , after 1 hour I checked it was done :)

Comment: Can you then please write something about my guess of slow internet as an answer to your own question and accept that? That way it doesn't stay an open question forever.

Comment: @Fabian I have answered but now I can am only able accept after 2 days.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: Well Its time for me to play minecraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is potentially caused by a slow network download speed.

Start downloading the new version, lock your PC and enjoy some tea or go out for a walk (just wait it out). After around 1 hour (considering that you have slow network speed), it should be completed; if not just keep waiting!

Comment: The size for a regular launcher plus assets (no saves, no versions but with game files) is approx 500mb, for me (hovering at like 100mb/s) it takes a matter of seconds, but since you are saying you have a download speed of 2mb/s it comes down to 250 sec or 5min (approx), taking into consideration of the speed of Mojang servers and transmission delays lets say your regular download speed drops to 100kb/s it would take 5000 sec or 83 min. If it were to take exactly 1 hour, your relative download speed would be 175k/s (approx). Your browsing speed is different from your download speed!

Comment: 2 more mobile phones are also connected to net.

Comment: Maybe they were dissconnected at that time. :)